# SharePoint 2010 security trimming custom global navigation with web.allusers

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am currently trying to security trim a global navigation that spans all site collections using xmlsitemapprovider. Everything is working properly, however because I am using web.allusers it doesn't display nodes unless the user is granted access explicitly. Since most of my permissions are based on Active Directory groups my users cannot see the nodes until after they have visited the site. How can I get the nodes to display for these users without them first having to visit the site?

```
public class CustomNavSecurityTrim : XmlSiteMapProvider
{

    public override bool IsAccessibleToUser(HttpContext context, SiteMapNode node)
    {
        try
        {
            if (node == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("node");
            }
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }
            if (!base.SecurityTrimmingEnabled)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Url))
            {
                return this.IsGranted(context, node.ChildNodes);
            }
            return this.IsGranted(context, node);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private bool IsGranted(HttpContext context, SiteMapNode node)
    {
        bool isGranted = false;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
            using (SPWeb web = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.MakeFullUrl(node.Url)).OpenWeb())
            {
                SPUser user = web.AllUsers[context.User.Identity.Name];
                if (user != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if ((node.Roles != null) && (node.Roles.Count > 0))
                        {
                            foreach (string str in node.Roles)
                            {
                                isGranted = (str == "*") || (user.Groups[str] != null);
                                if (isGranted)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        isGranted = web.DoesUserHavePermissions(user.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.EmptyMask | SPBasePermissions.ViewPages);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return isGranted;
    }

    private bool IsGranted(HttpContext context, SiteMapNodeCollection childNodes)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        foreach (SiteMapNode node in childNodes)
        {
            flag = this.IsGranted(context, node);
            if (flag)
            {
                return flag;
            }
            this.IsGranted(context, node.ChildNodes);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the nodes to display for these users without them first having to visit the site?

You would have to call [`SPWeb.EnsureUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) for each new user. This method causes SharePoint to 'retrieve' the given user's account and make it 'pre-known' to SharePoint.

---

However, what's more important, you should performance-test your solution. You are elevating privileges and opening a new `SPWeb` instance in each call to `IsGranted()`, which is in turn called several times. That could cause a severe performance bottleneck.

I would advice rethinking what you are trying to achieve (which I'm not getting in detail from your question) to be more in-line with SharePoint's architecture.

Comment: I have over 45 site collections, I am attempting to implement global navigation utilizing an xmlsitemapprovider which I need to be security trimmed via SharePoint permissions.  Can you provide an example of how to use `EnsureUser` in this solution?

Comment: The problem Ondrej is talking about is that if you implement your navigation like this and the commands are executed **for each user** **every time**, you will have performance bottlenecks. You would need to implement some kind of caching so the access rights are not always recalculated.

Comment: Is there a way to `EnsureUser` on user creation maybe using powershell? How would I go about caching the user's access rights? I'm not asking you to write the code but if you could provide an example or possible solution I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: A possible way to speed it up is to cache result on the user session this way it is cached for that particular user for that session